# Figuring out the miss rate of a direct mapped cache during execution of a for loop

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture

Say I have a direct-mapped cache with 1024 lines each of size 16 bytes. A, B and C are also stored in memory contiguously. I run the following for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
    C[i] = A[i] + B[i];
}
```

I am quite confused about how a direct-mapped cache works in this situation. This was my reasoning:

On the first iteration of the loop, there is a cache miss. A[0] - A[15] and B[0]-B[15] are cached. Then for the next 15 iterations of the loop, all cache requests result in a hit. So for 1024 iterations, every 16th iteration is a miss. So there are a total of 64 cache misses in this loop.

Is my reasoning right? And also, what if my loop runs through 2000 iterations instead of 1024? With the limited information I have, would it be possible to estimate the number of cache misses in this situation too? It seems like the problem is greatly simplified if I don't have to consider situations where the cache needs to be overwritten.